# Как вытащить св-ва Axios и присвоить их глобальным переменным?

Tags: javascript, node.js, асинхронность, axios

Есть такой код:

```
let sublInk = '';
let corporations_id = '';

function getUrlAndId(param){
  
  return axios.post("http://seo-gmbh.eu/invest/input.php",)
    
    .then(response => {
      sublInk = response.data.id;
      corporations_id = response.data.finanzen_net;
    })
    
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

getUrlAndId();
```

Вопрос: 
Каким образом необходимо сделать вызов функции `getUrlAndId()` что бы внутренние значения св-в `Axois`-a
 `response.data.id` и `response.data.finanzen_net` смогли автоматом присвоится более глобальным переменным:
`let sublInk = '';`
`let corporations_id = '';`
после ее вызова.

Comment: не надо задавать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз.

Comment: это разные вопросы это первое
и второе первый вопрос уже убран из выдачи на сколько я понимаю(а удалить я его не могу)
+ ответа не него нет корректно работающего - линки дубликаты не решают совершенно мой вопрос

Comment: линки конечно не решают, по линкам расположена информация объясняющая что делать и почему твой код не работает. Вопросы дубликаты, так как и там и тут ты хочешь получить значения из асинхронной функции. В вопросе дубликате - описано что именно и как нужно сделать

Comment: мне дубликат никак не помагает решить вопрос - где там конкретно описано как из Axois запроса вытащить св-ва на более глобальный уровень + присвоить их переменным автоматом??

Comment: axios возвращает promise, как работать с promise указано в дубликатах.

Comment: у меня не работают те  решения.
мне необходимо что бы показали работающий пример в моем случае.

Comment: твой случай точно такой же как в дубликатах - просто подставь свою функцию.

Comment: У меня это не работает - либо я делаю что то не так либо не там - мне необходим пример.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112009/discussion-between-grundy-and-mike-kharkov).